# Finding the range of $3+\frac{3}{2}\sin 2\theta + 2\cos 2\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

> How to find range of this function?
> $$3+\frac{3}{2}\sin 2\theta + 2\cos 2\theta$$

The original equation I had was
$$\sin^2\theta+ 3\sin \theta \cos \theta +5\cos^2 \theta$$
If possible, can I also find range from original directly?

Comment: See for example [Ranges in trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898806/ranges-in-trigonometry).

Comment: You can look here too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855431/how-do-i-find-the-range-of-y-a-sin-x-b-cos-x

Comment: Thanks @bigbang and dxiv , i resolved my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that simplifying the original formula as you have done was the right approach. Continuing, it can be written as

$3+\frac 3 2 \sin 2\theta+2 \cos 2\theta$

$=3+A\cos(\phi+2\theta)$ for some constants A and $\phi$

But since $A=\sqrt {\left(\frac 3 2\right)^2+ 2^2}=\frac 5 2$ we have,

$=3+ \frac 5 2 \cos(\phi+2\theta)$

and cos ranges from $-1$ to $1$ so our formula ranges from $\frac 1 2$ to $\frac {11} 2$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to this could be finding extrema of your function.

That is, take the first derivative of the function, put it to zero and find roots. I won't go further, because this is well known schema, read about it [here](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der14/der14.html).